# How to set MIME type for uploaded file?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, mime-types

I wrote this code to upload file  to database  by using asp.net and C#  . 
// this part to get the binary data and file name and  MIME  type

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(uploadcontract.FileName);
        if (filename != string.Empty)
        {
            String Conttype = uploadcontract.PostedFile.ContentType;
            Stream str = uploadcontract.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(str);
            Byte[] size = br.ReadBytes((int)str.Length);
            return size;
        }
        else
        {
           // do something
        }
```

after saving the file in the database successfully with name and MIME type  . i tried to download the same file with this code

```
 SqlCommand SelectCMD = new SqlCommand();
    sqlconn = new SqlConnection((String)ViewState["ConnStr"]);
    SelectCMD.CommandText = @"SELECT    tbl_Files_FileName,tbl_Files_FileContent,tbl_Files_FileMIME     FROM         tbl_Files            WHERE Seq=@sq";
    SelectCMD.Connection = sqlconn;
    SelectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("sq", Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
    SelectCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sda.SelectCommand = SelectCMD;
    int itemin = sda.Fill(ds, "downfile");
    sqlconn.Close();
    if (itemin != 0)
    {
            byte[] byt = (Byte[])ds.Tables["downfile"].Rows[0]["tbl_Files_FileContent"];
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = ds.Tables["downfile"].Rows[0]["tbl_Files_FileMIME"].ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + ds.Tables["downfile"].Rows[0]["tbl_Files_FileName"].ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byt);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

but i faced the following problem

Excel found unreadable content in "test.xlsx".Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? if you trust the source of this workbook, click yes.

it is look like there is problem with type of the file

Comment: the part for uploading  is omitted if any one want it let me know

Comment: I always recommend not to store files (like images and excel spreadsheets) in the database, but instead use the server's file system to store the files (what it is made for), and use the database only to store a handle (url) to the uploaded file.  This has many benefits, including making the uploaded file accessible to virus scans on the server.

Comment: I agree with you ,  but I am trying to save some trusted files . I want understand why I faced this problem . is it really based on the  MIME type ?  . by the  way I uploaded the file from my desktop and then saved it or downloaded it  in the  documents folder as a  test , I noticed the file content corrupted according to message I received   . this problem happened with .xlsx files  and .docx . with other types nothing  happened  .